# How does a hidden service know all ed25519 public keys?

Tags: onion-services, directory, hsdir

A hidden service needs all ed25519 public keys of all nodes to construct indexes which are used to get the responsible hidden service directories. I know you can get a public key by sending the request: http://<authority>/tor/server/fp/<fp>. It won't send one specific request at the time for every node I guess, so how does the hidden service know all public keys?